# update QStyle in EnterEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

i wanna update the QStyle of the LineEdit while the mouse is in\out the widget (enterEvent\leaveEvent ) i tried to add a bool variable to the drawPrimitive function but i get this error
TypeError: drawPrimitive(self, QStyle.PrimitiveElement, QStyleOption, QPainter, widget: QWidget = None): 'a' is not a valid keyword argument

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PushButton_2 import Push_Button_
import sys

class LineEditStyle(QProxyStyle):
    def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget,a=None):
        if a :
            self.pen = QPen(QColor('green'))
        else :
            self.pen = QPen(QColor('red'))
        self.pen.setWidth(4)
        if element == QStyle.PE_FrameLineEdit:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(self.pen)
            painter.drawRoundedRect(QRect(0,0,400,40), 10, 10)
        else:
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)

        
class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.a = 0
    
    def enterEvent(self, a0):
        self.a = 1

    def leaveEvent(self, a0):
        self.a = 0
        
    def paintEvent(self,event):
        option = QStyleOption()
        option.initFrom(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_FrameLineEdit,option,a=self.a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(500,500,400,400)
    window.setStyleSheet('background-color:#373737')
    line = LineEdit(parent=window)
    line.setGeometry(20,200,400,40)
    style = LineEditStyle()
    line.setStyle(style)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mustn't use the QStyleSheet with the QStyle because it makes a confusion and you have to set the default parameter Widget as None

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PushButton_2 import Push_Button_
import sys

class LineEditStyle(QProxyStyle):
    def drawPrimitive(self, element, option, painter, widget=None,a=None):
        if a :
            self.pen = QPen(QColor('green'))
        else :
            self.pen = QPen(QColor('red'))
        self.pen.setWidth(4)
        if element == QStyle.PE_FrameLineEdit:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
            painter.setPen(self.pen)
            painter.drawRoundedRect(QRect(0,0,400,40), 10, 10)
        else:
            super().drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget)
    
    def subElementRect(self, element, option, widget):
        if element == QStyle.SE_LineEditContents :
            return QRect(0,0,50,30)
        else :
            return super().subElementRect(element, option, widget)
    
    def drawItemText(self, painter, rect, flags, pal, enabled, text, textRole):
        rect_ = QRect(20,20,50,50)
        text = text.upper()
        painter.drawText(text,rect_,Qt.AlignCenter)
        
class LineEdit(QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        QLineEdit.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.a = 0
    
    def enterEvent(self, a0):
        self.a = 1

    def leaveEvent(self, a0):
        self.a = 0
        
    def paintEvent(self,event):
        option = QStyleOption()
        option.initFrom(self)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_FrameLineEdit,option,painter,a=self.a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setGeometry(500,500,400,400)
    #window.setStyleSheet('background-color:#373737')
    line = LineEdit(parent=window)
    line.setGeometry(20,200,400,40)
    style = LineEditStyle()
    line.setStyle(style)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: "You mustn't use the QStyleSheet with the QStyle because it makes a confusion" this is not completely accurate: the problem exists if a stylesheet is directly applied (and has effect) to the widget, or if any stylesheet set on a parent (including the application) affects the widget, and that's because in that case the *actual* style set and used is QStyleSheetStyle, which acts as a proxy to the style eventually set for the widget. In this specific case the problem is that the mouse over check was not done properly, which is by verifying if `option.state & QStyle.State_MouseOver`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [QStyleSheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) useful for something like this.

I mocked this up in Qt Designer by entering the following in styleSheet property (in code you would do `mywidget.setStyleSheet('<parameters>')` ):

```
QLineEdit {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
QLineEdit:focus {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

**Edit**: styleSheet string above works on focus, but the original question was about enterEvent/leaveEvent, which trigger on mouse hover. As @musicamente rightfully points out, to work on mouse hover the `:hover` [pseudo state](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states) can be used instead of `:focus`:

```
QLineEdit {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
QLineEdit:hover {
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

I made a QMainWindow with 2 QLineEdits: 1 has styleSheet set and the other is default. When the focus moves to the regular QLineEdit, the modified QLineEdit turns red.

[image]

You can make **ALL** of the QLineEdits behave the same by editing the styleSheet of their parent. In your case, you could use `window.setStyleSheet('....`. Here's another mockup in Qt Designer:

[image]

Comment: The OP didn't ask about the focus, but the mouse hover, which is achieved using the `:hover` pseudo state selector.

Comment: @musicamente. You're right! I didn't read the docs for [enterEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent) until your comment. enterEvent triggers on mouse hover. Answer edited to include `:hover`.